# Query return blank rows

Tags: sql

I understand how to return blank rows by using a left join but that doesnt work for me here.  Does anyone have some advice on how to return blank rows not related to a join but in relation to the where.  Im looking to pickup the most recent row for each member and this works for all active members that have an end dated row but in the case where their TERMDATE <> to Null I need to either return a blank row or pickup the most recent row.  Any and all help is much appreciated.
Thanks

```
SELECT MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS.AUTHNUMBER, CLIENTS.SUBSCRIBERID, MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS.AUTHTYPE, MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS.AUTHSTATUS,  GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE.LOB, GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE.ENROLLMENTDATE, GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE.TERMDATE
FROM GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE 
INNER JOIN CLIENTS 
ON GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE.PARENTID = CLIENTS.ID 
INNER JOIN MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS 
ON CLIENTS.ID = MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS.PARENTID
WHERE (MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS.AUTHTYPE = 1234) 
AND (GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE.TERMDATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Im using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window/analytic functions that can really help with this sort of query.  In particular, you can use the `dense_rank()` function to enumerate the rows for each group of `GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE` records, so a `NULL` termination date comes first, followed by the the termination dates in descending order.  You just need to choose the first one:

```
SELECT sa.AUTHNUMBER, ci.SUBSCRIBERID, sa.AUTHTYPE, sa.AUTHSTATUS,
       ci.LOB, ci.ENROLLMENTDATE, ci.TERMDATE
FROM (select ci.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by parentid
                                order by (case when termdate is null then 0 else 1 end),
                                         termdate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from GRDSHSCLIENTINSURANCE ci
     ) ci INNER JOIN
     CLIENTS c
     ON ci.PARENTID = c.ID INNER JOIN
     MCSERVICEAUTHORIZATIONS sa
     ON c.ID = sa.PARENTID
WHERE sa.AUTHTYPE = 1234 AND
      ci.seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this query uses `dense_rank()`.  This allows multiple rows to be returned, in the even that there are two rows that both have `NULL` values.

Also, I added table aliases to make the query more readable.

Comment: Having some issues with this hopefully I can get it to work.  Thanks